# How to register a table for callableStatement

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I've got the following procedure:

```
procedure GetContractInfo(RequestID number, ParamNames out TVarcharArray, ParamValues out TVarcharArray,
                                 SessionID in IRBiS_Const.TSessionID default null);

type TVarcharArray is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;
```

How can I register `ParamValues out TVarcharArray` using callableStatement? This is my effort:

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY,"VARCHAR2");
```

But server says

> WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error:
>   17074, SQLState: 99999
>
> ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -
>   invalid template name(that was roughly translated): POOL_REQUESTHANDLER.VARCHAR2

Answer (score 0):

From java you only can access schema level collection.
Try this. 
Oracle

```
 create or replace type TVarcharArray is table of varchar2(255); --(without index by binary_integer)
```

And java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
    Connection con = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection();
    CallableStatement cl = con.prepareCall("declare " +
                                            " a TVarcharArray;" +
                                            " begin " +
                                            "  a := TVarcharArray('A','B','C');" +
                                            "  ? := a;" +
                                            " end;\n" +
                                            "");
    cl.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY,"TVARCHARARRAY");
    cl.execute();
    String[] objArr = (String[]) (cl.getArray(1)).getArray();
    for(String tmp: objArr){
        System.err.println(tmp);
    }
    con.close();

}
```